# How to use avplayerviewcontroller to embed video in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

I am using a TableView to display list of post,which contain either image or video, I would like to embed Video in table view cell, can we use avplayerviewcontroller for the same and how it would work with table view cell 
Also auto play would be add on

Comment: Please share the code you've written and explain why it doesn't work or doesn't do what you want.